# Is it possible to create and use window function in the same query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using `PostgreSQL` and I have the following situation:

table of `Sales` (short version):

```
itemid quantity
  5      10
  5      12
  6       1
```

table of `stock` (short version):

```
itemid stock
5        30
6         1
```

I have a complex query that also needs to present in one of it's columns the `SUM` of each `itemid`.

So it's going to be:

```
Select other things,itemid,stock, SUM (quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY itemid) AS total_sales
from .....
     sales
     stock
```

This query is OK. however this query will present:

```
itemid stock total_sales
  5       30     22
  6       1       1
```

But I don't need to see `itemid=6` because the whole stock was sold. meaning that I need a `WHERE` condition like:

```
WHERE total_sales<stock
```

but I can't do that as the `total_sales` is created after the `WHERE` is done.

Is there a way to solve this without surrounding the whole query with another one? I'm trying to avoid it if I can.

Comment: Using a derived table (that's the technical term for what you call "*surrounding the query with another one*") is the only way to solve this. Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: This is just an example of my problem in simple words... In my case I have 4 columns which are dependent on the result of the window function of the other... so it will be 4 derived tables....

Comment: I don't see why that would make it four derived tables - just one (or a CTE) with four aliases. You should post the **complete** query.

Comment: ok.. I thought there might be a way around it... I'll use CTE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery or CTE:

```
select s.*
from (Select other things,itemid,stock,
             SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY itemid) AS total_sales
      from .....
     ) s
where total_sales < stock;
```

You cannot use table aliases defined in a `SELECT` in the `SELECT`, `WHERE`, or `FROM` clauses for that `SELECT`.  However, a subquery or CTE gets around this restriction.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an inner select in your `WHERE` statement like this:

```
SELECT *, SUM (quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY itemid) AS total_sales
FROM t
WHERE quantity <> (SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM t ti WHERE t.itemid = ti.itemid);
```

Comment: The solution with a derived table is going to be much faster.